# Aruco Marker Tracking With Multiple Markers From the Same Dictionary

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I'm using `ChAruCo marker tracking` from `OpenCV Contrib`.   I'd like to track multiple boards, but the mechanism to create the marker boards is not as I would expect.

What I picture is having one dictionary **(Say, DICT_4X4_50)** to create many markers using distinct ID ranges from the dictionary.
`CharucoBoard::create()` accepts the dictionary and uses markers 0-X to create the board.  I'd like to add an offset to the beginning of the range.

If I can create the boards, `cv::aruco::detectMarkers()` outputs IDs which can determine which board is in view.  Is this supported, and if not, how should I go about tracking more than one target?

Comment: If i understood your question, to add an offset. i.e by 5, you generate a dictionary of 55 markers, and you use only starting from 5 to 55 (you neglect the first five markers. The second question to determine which board is in view, it does already this task, Otherwise  this points is not clear for me

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add an offset to the elements in the vector ids in the `Board` class. I can't tell you whether this is "supported", but we used it for non charuco boards and it worked fine.
Since the charuco board indices `nearestMarkerIdx` are indices into the `ids` vector this should work out fine.

```
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::CharucoBoard> board1 =  cv::aruco::CharucoBoard::create(3, 5, 0.32f, 0.08f, dictionary);
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::CharucoBoard> board2 = cv::aruco::CharucoBoard::create(3, 5, 0.32f, 0.08f, dictionary);
int id_offset_board2 = board1->ids.size();
for(auto& id: board2->ids)
{
    id += id_offset_board2;
}
```