# How to generate charuco board with ids offset

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I am using *Charuco marker* from *Opencv* in python. I was previously using *Aruco* board where I had the option to create a board with and id offset (e.g: offset of 40).

```
from cv2 import aruco as ar
ar_dict = ar.getPredefinedDictionary(ar.DICT_6X6_1000)
board = ar.ar.GridBoard_create(markersX=sizeX, markersY=sizeY, markerLength=0.04, markerSeparation=0.01, dictionary=ar_dict, firstMarker=40)
```

However, it looks like the option is not available for *Charuco* board. The closest solutions I found was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379508/aruco-marker-tracking-with-multiple-markers-from-the-same-dictionary) in C++, However, the option is not working in python as the ids are not writable.

```
board = ar.CharucoBoard_create(15, 7, 1, .8, ar_dict)
board.ids += 10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-410d8ac9fdda> in <module>
----> 1 board.ids += 10

AttributeError: attribute 'ids' of 'cv2.aruco_Board' objects is not writable
```

Does anyone know if there are other alternatives in python to add offset to the marker ids when creating a Charuco board object?

**Edit September 2021**

It looks like the option to set ids is now available in python with this commit: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/7e7fbbae3ab09a026f2a350467615abd77146808#diff-1e04b23f84e112e319f8019cb9963379a43271b15bea09259638e3dfa386bd4a. Running version of Opencv 4.5.3 the board ids can now be modified with success.

```
from cv2 import aruco as ar
ar_dict = ar.getPredefinedDictionary(ar.DICT_6X6_1000)
board = ar.CharucoBoard_create(15, 7, 1, .8, ar_dict)
board.ids += 10
```

Comment: Same problem using a custom build of OpenCV 4.1.0: I've also checked the source code to see the member specifiers, however `CV_PROP std::vector< int > ids` is public as expected. Which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: I am using OpenCV 4.0.0 which also have `CV_PROP std::vector< int > ids` in public. I am not familiar with the python wrapping method, but I see that there is `CV_PROP` and `CV_PROP_RW`. The difference between both is briefly explain [here](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_bindings/py_bindings_basics/py_bindings_basics.html). Someone [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/554) is suggesting that `CV_PROP` doesn't allow writeable property contrary to `CV_PROP_RW`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
from cv2 import aruco

aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_5X5_250)
aruco_dict.bytesList=aruco_dict.bytesList[30:,:,:]
board = aruco.CharucoBoard_create(7, 5, 1, 0.5, aruco_dict)

imboard = board.draw((2000, 2000))
cv2.imwrite("chessboard1.png", imboard)
```

you can change the bytesList of the aruco_dict

Comment: This will change the printed board, but won't help with you detections